# Taking off the chip from Arduino

Tags: atmega328

I just uploaded a sketch of a song to my Arduino and it works well.  Could I just take the chip out and hook up speakers to it and a power source to play the song? and just get another chip and put it in the Arduino.

Comment: There are lots of resources on this subject on the internet.
It is possible, but requires some engineering.
Try searching: "Breadboard arduino" or "barebones arduino".
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone

You'll need:
5V power supply, or circuitry to provide so.
20Mhz clock or use the internal 8Mhz clock.
Something to program it with, an USB<->uart converter or ICSP programmer. (Or just put a programmed chip in)
And optionally a reset button,

Comment: @FuaZe arduinos use 16MHz, not 20mHz.

Comment: @Gerben ah, ofcourse, no idea why I thought of 20Mhz. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

To elaborate, the sketch you downloaded to the chip has been flashed to internal non-volatile memory. So if you were to move it to *another* Arduino board or other device with the appropriate support hardware, then it should work just fine.

However, if you're intending to directly hook-up speakers to it and a power source, then I highly doubt it's going to work. You really need some support hardware for the chip (such as an external clock - though I think the Atmega328 has an internal clock, decoupling capacitors, amplifiers for the spearkers, etc.).

Comment: More specifically, the ATmega328p in a typical full-size Arduino is typically fused to rely on an external clock.  While being provided with such a clock it can be re-programmed for internal clock operation, as those used on some of the various smaller boards typically are.

Answer (score 0):

Easy part first: You CAN put another chip on arduino PROVIDED that chip already has a bootloader on it. If it's a raw chip, burn the bootloader on it first. [This guide will help](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).

You CAN connect the programmed chip to speaker PROVIDED you add the minimal circuit components required for an arduino to run. These include - a 16 MHz crystal, two 22 pf capacitors and a 10K resistor. Use the schematic in the bootloader guide. That will work.

Besides this, you will require a 5V power source. You can alternatively use 3xAA cells (4.5V will work perfectly). Alternatively use a wall adapter of 7V or higher and use a linear regulator (7805) to generate a perfect 5V supply for your arduino. You will need this pin mapping diagram to connect the speaker to arduino once you take it out from the board:

[image]